# Crash when gerate click by a button in an empty gridview list

Tags: c#, gridview

When I gerate a click in the gridview with this code :

```
 dataGridView1_CellClick(dataGridView1, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(0, 0));
```

on an empty gridview, this error occurs:

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."
```

on this line of code:

```
 DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
```

My question is how do I avoid this error?
Thank you!

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid`!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type.. - You need to check on the e.RowIndex! It can be -1 for the headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `dataGridView1_CellClick`, you need to check that the index is greater than zero before you attempt to access an element from `Rows`.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
       //Don't want this to execute when the column header/row is clicked (OOB)
        if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
              return;

        DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
 }
```